# ¿Como modifico un iframe por medio de javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html5

El problema es el siguiente. Tengo un total de 4 iframes dentro de mi sitio web, el unico que se mueve es el de contenido los demás se quedan inmóviles, el que se mueve constantemente no tiene problemas, la cuestión cambia cuando uno de los otros frames debería ponerse por debajo del de contenido o moverse a un lado para que este no le estorbe al principal, ya que si lo dejo así, no puedo dar click al principal porque este esta puesto debajo del mismo ya lo eh intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
        <script>

    function ocultar() {
        window.parent.frames[3].document.body.style.display = "none";

    }


    </script>
```

Esta función debería de ocultarme el frame y lo hace en cierta medida, ya que lo que me oculta es lo que hay dentro del frame y yo no quiero eso, sino que todo el marco del frame sea desvanecido, ocultado o movido en alguna dirección que no me estorbe, a continuacion les dejo el como esta acomodado mis frames

```
<body onload="ocultar()"   >

    <div >

        <center><label style="font-family: titulo;font-size: 42px;color: red;">Proyecto Hidruth</label></center>
        <center> <div ><iframe name="frame-menu" id="framemenu" src="PHP/menu.php"></iframe></div></center>
        <div ><center><iframe   style="border-width: 0px;background-color: #393030;background-color: #c3b6b6;"  id="informacion2" src="PHP/ayudas/ayuda.inicio.php"></iframe></center></div>
        <div ><center><iframe name="frame-contenido" id="frameinicio" style="z-index: -10000;" src="PHP/inicio.php"></iframe></center></div>
        <div ><center><iframe id="frame-articulo" name="frame-articulo" style="float: right;margin-top: -10%;margin-left: -45%;width:60%;height: 92%;margin-top: -50%;z-index: 1000;position: absolute;"   src="PHP/articulos/inicio_articulos.php"></iframe></center></div>

        <div><center><iframe  style="background-color: orangered;border:0;border-radius: 5px;" id="framepie"  src="PHP/piepagina.php"></iframe></center></div>
    </div> 






</body>
```

de antemano gracias por leer mi comentario.

Codigo para ocultar:

```
        function ocultar() {
```

document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZbIv.png).style.display = "none";

```
    }
```

codigo para mostrar:

```
function articulos() {
window.parent.frames[2].location = "articulos.php"
window.parent.frames[1].location = "ayudas/ayuda.articulos.php"
    alert(document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[3]);

document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[3].style.display = "block";


var scary = document.getElementById("scary");
scary.play();
```

}

Cuando carga inicialmente todos los frames si oculta el que yo requiero:

[image: Ventana de Inicio]

Cuando doy click en el menu articulos deberia reaparecer el frame que inicialmente lo oculte y me sale este error

[image: Ventana de articulos]

El orden de mis elementos es el siguiente:
En javascript se en cuentra mi archivo donde hago la accion de articulos
y en php cargo todos mis frames y al mismo tiempo oculto el que no necesito inicialmente

[image: orden de elementos]

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir una imagen tipo esquema para entender como quieres disponer los iframes? Si tus iframes fueran "Responsive creo que te solucionarían el problema".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás aplicando el estilo al `iframe` sino al `body` de la página dentro del `iframe`. Entonces sigues con el mismo problema porque el `iframe` en sí sigue siendo visible y sigue estorbando a la hora de hacer click.

La solución sería aplicar los estilos directamente al `iframe`. Eso lo puedes hacer de diferentes formas dependiendo de cómo tengas estructurada la página:

- Si el `iframe` tiene un `id` entonces aplica el estilo directamente al elemento con ese `id`:

  ```
  function ocultar() {
      document.getElementById("iframe-a-ocultar").style.display = "none";
  }
  ```
- Si los `iframe`s no tienen `id`y quieres ocultar el cuarto, podrías hacer algo como esto:

  ```
  document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[3].style.display = "none";
  ```

  o esto:

  ```
  // CUIDADO: los contadores de nth-child empiezan en 1 en lugar de 0 :S
  document.querySelector("iframe:nth-child(4)").style.display = "none";
  ```

  lo que dejaría la función `ocultar()` así:

  ```
  function ocultar() {
      document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[3].style.display = "none";
  }
  ```

Comment: muchas gracias alvaro ya eh podido resolver una parte del problema, solo que ahora no se a que motivo se deba de que lo oculta y todo es correcto lo hizo como quería, pero el problema es que cuando de en cierta opción de mi menú debería de volverlo a habilitar y eh ahí el nuevo problema ya que cuando le digo que lo vuelva aparecer lo puse dentro de un alert y me marca como undefinied el frame numero tres dentro de mi archivo de javascript, ya que de ahi hago todos los movimientos y pues solo lo oculta sin poder volverlo aparecer

Comment: @David ¿Puedes compartir en la pregunta el código de cómo lo escondes y lo muestras?¿Te aparece algún error en la consola de JS?

Comment: ya hice la edicion